# Python List Variable - Is it using the memory location or something?

Tags: python

I'm trying to pop off the values I'm appending to the list M each time I've evaluated the difference between them and their expected values. I'm printing the result of a list before and after I use `M.pop()`. Is it using a location in memory and messing up my list inside of deltaL?

```
M=[]
delta = 3
while abs(delta) > 0.3:
    for num1 in range(450,800,20):
        best_config_per_numL = []
        delta_mL = []
        for config in ['FFF','FFS','FSF','FSS','SFF','SFS','SSF','SSS']:
            M.append(gen(num1,config[0]))
            M.append(gen(num1,config[1]))
            M.append(gen(num1,config[2]))

            xyL = []
            xL = range(400,801,1)
            for i in xL:
                xyL.append([geny(M,i),i])

            deltaL = []
            yL = range(400,801,1)
            for i in range(len(yL)):
                expected = yL[i]
                actual = xyL[i][0].real
                deltaL.append(abs(expected - actual))

            delta_mL.append([max(deltaL),M]) 
            print '\n'+str(delta_mL)+'\n' #<-------------------------- LINE 1
            M.pop()
            M.pop()
            M.pop()
        print '\n'+str(delta_mL)+'\n' #<-------------------------- LINE 2
        best_config_per_numL.append(delta_mL[0].sort()[0]) #best config for all lambda

    M.append(best_config_per_numL.sort()[0][1])
    delta = best_config_per_numL.sort()[0][0]
```

**The output of LINE 1 is:**
[[1.0, [[1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]]]

[[1.0, [[1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.99749174811000929, [[1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]]]

[[1.0, [[1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.99749174811000929, [[1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.90639755394574695, [[1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]]]

[[1.0, [[1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.99749174811000929, [[1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.90639755394574695, [[1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.78984872616045532, [[1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]]]

[[1.0, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.99749174811000929, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.90639755394574695, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.78984872616045532, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.99749174811000885, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]]]

[[1.0, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.99749174811000929, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.90639755394574695, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.78984872616045532, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.99749174811000885, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.77268527172444679, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]]]

[[1.0, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.99749174811000929, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.90639755394574695, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.78984872616045532, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.99749174811000885, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.77268527172444679, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]], [0.78984872616045532, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.9736842105263157, 57.0]]]]

[[1.0, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.99749174811000929, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.90639755394574695, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.78984872616045532, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.99749174811000885, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.77268527172444679, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [0.78984872616045532, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]], [1.0, [[1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0], [1.0514018691588785, 107.0]]]]

**The output of LINE 2 is:**
[[1.0, []], [0.99749174811000929, []], [0.90639755394574695, []], [0.78984872616045532, []], [0.99749174811000885, []], [0.77268527172444679, []], [0.78984872616045532, []], [1.0, []]]

I expected to get the same thing as LINE 1.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I assume the root cause is yet another misunderstanding of what Python's varibles are. But I can make little sense of what exact problem you're having.

Comment: Please don't print "str(something)".  It looks confusing and does nothing..  Please replace all of your `print...str(...)...` with simpler `print "\n", max(deltaL), M, "\n"`

Comment: Also, the code is not correctly indented, "LINE 2" has 7 leading spaces. In my answer I supposed that they were 8.

Comment: As I told you, you cannot get the same value that you have in LINE 1 because LINE 2 is in a different part of the program, where the M list is empty.

Comment: I've updated the question. The print line I was showing previously was an obvious answer. The new print line error is more difficult.

Comment: `delta_mL[0].sort()[0]` raises an error, so how does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
delta_mL.append([max(deltaL),M])
```

...creates a list with two items, the second of which is a *reference* to the list M. When you later change M, you can see the changes in delta_mL because it references the same list. If you want to make a *copy* of M, try:

```
delta_mL.append([max(deltaL),list(M)])
```

This will create a new list that contains the same items as M, but that is a separate copy so that it won't change when you add or remove items in M.

Remember that in Python, variables store *references* to objects. If you want to make a copy of an object, you need to do so explicitly. This is, of course, only important when the objects in question are *mutable*, like lists are. Immutable objects - such as numbers, tuples and strings - aren't a problem, because even if many variables store references to the same immutable object, none of them can modify it, so sharing is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it using a location in memory and messing up my list inside of deltaL?

In a way.

```
delta_mL.append([max(deltaL),M])
```

`delta_mL` has a **reference** to `M`.  Not a copy of `M`.  If `M` changes, so does `delta_mL`.

You might not want to simply append `M`.  You might want to use `M[:]` to make a copy of `M`.

Comment: Updated the post to more accurately reflect my question.